# Visual C++ 2010: what major c++0x (and STL) features are still missing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

is there atomic_ operations? thread? bind? what is still missing?

EDIT: i'm interesting in c++0x and its STL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definitive list, but here are some resources that show what’s missing:

- [Apache C++0x Compiler Support Report](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)
- [Scott Meyers’ Summary of C++0x Feature Availability](http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm)

Note on the second link you should click on the tabs on the bottom of the page to see the reports.

- Generalized binders, from TR1, are in MSVC 10.
- Atomic types, [N2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html), are not in MSVC 10 yet.
- Threads, [N2184](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2184.html), are not in MSVC 10 yet.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [here](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx)
[image]

Comment: @prasoon: tnx, also I edited question, included STL too. I'm still interested in automic ops, thread and bind

Comment: @AndyT : Did you check out both the links?

Comment: @AndyT : MSVC++2010 doesn't support C++0x atomic types and threads.

Comment: Ugh - next time you paste in a screen capture, configure your ClearType for RGB order not BGR.